# Scrapy crawl page of urls, extract value from each new page

Tags: python, scrapy

First post here and I am pretty new to scrapy. I am trying to crawl a page of .htm urls:
https://www.bls.gov/bls/news-release/empsit.htm#2008

and extract two datapoints from each crawled page, saving each iteration to a csv file using Scrapy.

Currently, I have:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class EmpsitSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "EmpsitSpider"
allowed_domains = ["bls.gov"]
start_urls = [
'https://www.bls.gov/bls/news-release/empsit.htm#2008'
]

rules = [
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(allow_domains=("bls.gov"), restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="bodytext"]/a[following-sibling::text()[contains(., ".htm")]]')), 
        follow= True, callback= "parse_items"),
        ]

def parse_items(self, response):
    self.logger.info("bls item page %s", response.url)
    item = scrapy.Item()
    item["SA"] = response.xpath(('//*[@id="ces_table1"]/tbody/tr[138]/td[8]/span')[0].text).extract()
    item["NSA"] = response.xpath(tree.xpath('//*[@id="ces_table1"]/tbody/tr[138]/td[4]/span')[0].text).extract()
    return item
```

then run

```
    scrapy crawl EmpsitSpider -o data.csv
```

I have hit a bottleneck with scrapy. I cannot loop through the html pages. I can extract the two datapoints from each page using their xpaths and lxml:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = 
requests.get('https://www.bls.gov/news.release/archives/empsit_01042019.htm')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#part time for economic reasons, seasonally adjusted
SA = tree.xpath('//*[@id="ces_table1"]/tbody/tr[138]/td[8]/span')[0].text
print(SA)

#part time for economic reasons, not seasonally adjusted
NSA = tree.xpath('//*[@id="ces_table1"]/tbody/tr[138]/td[4]/span')[0].text
print(NSA)
```

I cannot get scrapy to loop through the urls. Any thoughts on how to proceed? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please share sample output you want to have

Comment: If you pasted your code correctly, then this is the syntax error in your Rule: `restrict_xpaths=("//div[@id="bodytext"]/a[following-sibling::text()[contains(., ".htm")]]")`. You have double quotes inside double quotes. Replace the outer double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: @Alderven I want the output to be a csv file as a N x 2 matrix where the first value of N is the earliest HTML report release and the last is the latest. The two column vectors are the variables [ SA , NSA ] to be pulled from a table that is found in the same location for each HTML link.

Comment: @malberts Thank you for your help on the syntax.

Comment: @jedens Can you get an updated version of your code without syntax errors running? Then we can check if there is still an issue with the loop.

Comment: @malberts Yes, it is now updated.

Comment: Please do not describe output format, just show some sample.

Comment: You're going to have to do a bit more work by yourself and come back with *specific* problems. I'll give you one more tip: to use the `rules` property you need to extend `CrawlSpider`, not `Spider`. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider).